# emitter follower output current

Tags: transistors, emitter-follower

Is the output current of an emitter follower out of phase with input current? In the book Electronic devices and Circuit Theory, the current gain, Ai, is negative. It depends on direction on output current Io.

[image]

[image]

you can see that output  current Io, is going from ground to resistor. The polarity of Vo is changed.Because from the diagram we see that Vo is taken between emitter and ground with polarity + (emitter),  -(ground). Im confused about this. Can anyone confirm what really the direction of Io is?

Answer (score 1):

IF the current is adopted as coming from ground, and its magnitude is negative, that is the same as saying that it goes into ground.

So the current is not inverted, and the output voltage is positive.

Answer (score 0):

The polarity drawn for the current in the diagram is unconventional.

Note that in fact what is shown is the current in the biasing resistor Re, not the output current (which would flow through the capacitor and into a load resistor (presumably to GND). The conventional way would then be the current in that load resistor to GND, and this is in phase with the input.

Answer (score 0):

the direction of Io means defined current by two-port network. transistor small signal ac equivalent circuit can be considered as two-port network. Io is defined as output current, and direction is flow into the system. so, actual output current Ie flow through RE, which means opposite with defined direction. And input current is flow into the  network, the direction is defined as positive. So, the current gain is negative. the input and output current are out of phase.